# Subsubsection in cleanthesis style

Tags: sectioning, cleanthesis

I am using the `cleanthesis.sty` and I would like to have numbered subsubsections, which are in style and format similar to the subsection, just a little bit smaller maybe. I tried editing the `*.sty` file directly, but had no success. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the following code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0em}{.5em}{0em}%[0pt]
\ifct@cthesis@hangsubsection
        \titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]%
            {\usekomafont{subsubsection}}%
            {\color{ctcolorblack}\thesubsubsection\hspace*{10pt}}%
            {0pt}%
            {\raggedright}%
            [\phantomsection]
\else
        \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]%
            {\usekomafont{subsubsection}}%
            {\color{ctcolorblack}\thesubsubsection\hspace*{10pt}}%
            {0pt}%
            {\raggedright}%
            [\phantomsection]
\fi
\makeatother
```

The line

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

gives you the correct numbering, while the rest of the code is to produce the title of the subsubsection similar to the one for subsections.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{cleanthesis}

\makeatletter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0em}{.5em}{0em}%[0pt]
\ifct@cthesis@hangsubsection
        \titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]%
            {\usekomafont{subsubsection}}%
            {\color{ctcolorblack}\thesubsubsection\hspace*{10pt}}%
            {0pt}%
            {\raggedright}%
            [\phantomsection]
\else
        \titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]%
            {\usekomafont{subsubsection}}%
            {\color{ctcolorblack}\thesubsubsection\hspace*{10pt}}%
            {0pt}%
            {\raggedright}%
            [\phantomsection]
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. :-) I nearly had the same code trying to edit the *.sty file...

Comment: @Mil Glad to help. Please consider accepting the answer (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)).

Comment: I accepted it. Thank you for letting me know about these functions - this is a great and well designed place. :)

I do have another short question: How do I change the font of this new subsubtitle, e.g. also make it in this color of the other titles?

Comment: @Mil Add the following in the preamble `\newcommand{\thesissubsubsectionfont}{\color{ctcolorsection}\tgherosfont} \setkomafont{subsubsection}{\thesissubsubsectionfont}`

Answer (score 0):

I have another short question. 
If I want to create a subsubsubsection or a numbered paragraph respectively, how can I change the code for that? I tried editing Karl's code, but it didn't work for me. I'd greatly appreciate your ideas. :-)

Edit: okay I managed on my own. Actually it was as easy as I expected it to be:

```
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\thesissubsubsectionfont\normalsize\itshape}
\makeatletter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} %unnumbered
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0em}{.4em}{0em}%[0pt]
\ifct@cthesis@hangsubsection
        \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]%
            {\usekomafont{paragraph}}%
            {\color{ctcolorblack}\theparagraph\hspace*{8pt}}%
            {0pt}%
            {\raggedright}%
            [\phantomsection]
\else
        \titleformat{\paragraph}[block]%
            {\usekomafont{paragraph}}%
            {\color{ctcolorblack}\theparagraph\hspace*{8pt}}%
            {0pt}%
            {\raggedright}%
            [\phantomsection]
\fi
\makeatother
```

Comment: OKay, I managed myself. Actually it was as easy as I thought it should be:

Comment: Asking another question in an answer and unaccepting mine is not correct at all. You should have asked a new question and gave your own answer...

Comment: Oh, I am sorry Karl - I didn'd realize that. I am new to stackexchange and these functions. I did not mean to unaccept your reply (which was a really great and helpful one) but wanted to indicate that my second question can be considered resolved. sorry for the misunderstanding. :-)

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you want small clarifications you can comment an answer, while when you want to ask something different you'd better ask a new question. In this case I suggest you to delete this answer and, if you want, ask it as a new question and give your own answer. :-)